# ASP.NET MVC 2 Parameter Array

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I need to have the following routing logic:

> http://mydomain.com/myAction/{root}/{child1}/{child2}/...

I don't know what is the depth of the route
so I want the action's signature to look something like that:

```
public ActionResult myAction(string[] hierarchy)
{
  ...
}
```

Have no idea how to write that route. Help?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you add the following mapping:

```
routes.MapRoute("hierarchy", "{action}/{*url}"
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

you can obtain the string 'url' in your action method:

```
public ActionResult myAction(string url)
{
    ...
}
```

The hierarchy is then easily obtained:

```
string[] hierarchy = url.Split('/');
```

Creating an url from a list of string values can be done using a similair approach:

```
string firstPart = hierarchy.Count() > 0: hierarchy[0] : string.Empty;
StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(firstPart);
for (int index = 1; index < hierarchy.Count(); index++)
{
    urlBuilder.Append("/");
    urlBuilder.Append(hierarchy[index]);
}
```

urlBuilder can then be used in an action link, for example:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Text", new { Controller="Home", Action="Index", Url=urlBuilder.ToString() }) %>
```

Comment: I haven't checked that yet but it seems to work. What about rendering a route link? I would like to pass an array as route data. Any Ideas?

Comment: I've added an approach to the post.

Comment: Works perfectly! It is a matter of style but instead of using writing urlBuilder, I used string.Join("/", strArray). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

for this problem your need to use strongly typed urlBuilder. Like T4MVC

Comment: Why would that help? Can you give an example?