# Asp.net mvc dynamic route for Categories tree

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Hi
Is it possible to create a route, who accepts X number of Categories/subCategories

```
mysite.com/CategoryName//ProductID/ProductName
mysite.com/CategoryName/Sub1CategoryName/ProductID/ProductName
mysite.com/CategoryName/Sub1CategoryName/Sub2Category/ProductID/ProductName
```

Of cource I could create a route for each possible combination, but I really don't know how deep my categories tree would be.

Maybe something with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own route handler, similar to what I posted in this answer:

[MVC route with array of homogeneous parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874625/mvc-route-with-array-of-homogeneous-parameters/3875438#3875438)