# ASP.NET MVC Routing with non standard url structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to ASP.NET MVC.

We are writing the basic architecture for a new website and are using asp.net mvc3 for the presentation layer.

On the business side it has been decided that our new site should use an url structure that reflects the data hierarchy.

Example of a fictive url: http://mycraftsite.com/profesionals/tailors/patterns/persian/mediastyle/kiefalpattern

This does not conform to the controller/action/id pattern that I see in a lot of examples. Can an url structure like ours fit the MVC concepts?

Thanks
Thomas Holme

Comment: could http://mycraftsite.com/patterns/persian/mediastyle/kiefalpattern/profesionals/tailors be equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define your own route handler, similar to what's done here:

[MVC route with array of homogeneous parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874625/mvc-route-with-array-of-homogeneous-parameters/3875438#3875438)

Answer (score 2):

Try use the route pattern

```
{controller}/{action}/{*parameters}
```

ex. Home/Index/Param1/Param2/Param3...

@HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index(object param1, object param2, object param3...) { }
```

the '*' indicates that route must match greedy parameters. So, now you can pass multiples parameters to your action method. Like the data hierarchy structure that you desire.

Hope it helps.